# How to redirect 404 error page with 404 response code to a custom page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I want to REDIRECT 404 error page to custom 404 page. For example, if http://example.com/abc.html causes 404 error, I want redirect the page to http://example.com/404.html with 404 http response code. It is possible?

Comment: It's possible, but it depends on your setup. What are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far there is NO OPTION to redirect 404 error page to a custom 404 page with 404 http response code. To get 404 http response code, you will need to display custom 404 error page content without redirection like following code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

And if you use following code, the 404 error page will be redirected to the custom 404 page with 302 http response code

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourdomain.com/404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache, you can use the `ErrorDocument` directive ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)).

You are encouraged to use an internal rewrite for this, so the client receives the correct statuscode for the request (404). If you make it redirect to this page, the client will receive a 301 or 302 header instead for the non-existing page, which can confuse automated webservices, such as webcrawlers.

To make it internally rewrite:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

To make it externally redirect

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://yoursite.com/404.html
```

Comment: I know, but the http response code for "ErrorDocument 404 http://yoursite.com/404.html" will be 302 instead of 404. I need 404 redirect with 404 http response code. Is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: The `3xx` range is used to denote redirects. While a redirect with a `404` header *may* work, it is not supported and I would strictly advice against it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html