# Redirect 4xx to a custom page with 200 response code in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I am trying to get any 403 request to go to a custom error page with 200 OK request (for security reason).

- Tried this to redirect any 4xx error code to a custom error page

  ```
  ErrorDocument 403 /shared/error.html
  ```

But this will not change the response code (it will still be 404).
There this option but it will give 302 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883365/how-to-redirect-404-error-page-with-404-response-code-to-a-custom-page-using-hta)

- Tried this to change the error code:

  ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/shared/.*/$ /shared/error.html [R=200,L]
  ```

But somehow it doesn't redirect to the custom error page I want to.

- Tried it with absolute path as well:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/shared/.*/$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/shared/error.html [R=200,L]
  ```

Still doesn't work. Is it not possible or am I missing something obvious? This is my first time modifying but I did some research already. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `ErrorDocument` for the code 200:

```
ErrorDocument 200 /shared/error.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/shared/.*/$ anything [R=200]
```

When the rule is applied it will execute the redirection to the ErrorDocument straight away, and that is the reason why you can put "anything" in there.

Check the documentation for the R flag (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html):

> The status code specified need not necessarily be a redirect (3xx) status code. However, if a status code is outside the redirect range (300-399) then the substitution string is dropped entirely, and rewriting is stopped as if the L were used.

Beware that you might not want this redirection for the whole code, so you should apply it within a context. And take cara with your regex so you don't fall in a loop.

Source: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you'd use a php-script for example instead of your static html-document, you can override the response code inside your script.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this by just modifying the httpd.conf?